# Tkinter - what's the Index of selected value in spinbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, indexing, tkinter

I've built a class for item selection with Tkinter Spinbox. I'd like to return the index of the selected item. Is that possible?

```
from Tkinter import *

class TestSpin():
  def __init__(self, i_root, i_friendlist):
    self.root = i_root
    self.root.friend = Spinbox(self.root, values = i_friendlist)
    self.root.friend.pack()
    self.root.okbutton = Button(self.root, text='Ok', command = lambda: self.ack())
    self.root.okbutton.pack()

  def ack(self):

# here I'd like to have the index of selected item in friendlist
    print "Index of "+self.root.friend.get()+" is [0 or 1 or 2]:", self.root.friend 
# here I'd like to have the index of selected item in friendlist

    self.root.destroy()

root = Tk()
list = ['Emma','Sarah','James']
app = TestSpin(root, list)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot for your advice. I tried self.root.friend.index(), but that method wants an argument which I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to directly get the value from the widget, but it's just one line of python code:

```
index = i_fiendlist.index(self.root.friend.get())
```

Using your code, you need to save the value of the list:

```
class TestSpin():
    def __init__(self, i_root,i_friendlist):
        self._list = i_list
        ...

    def ack(self):
        value = self.root.friend.get()
        index = self._list.index(value)
        print "Index of " + value + " is " + str(index)
        self.root.destroy()
```

Comment: Hey Bryan, thanks a lot! I very much appreciate your work here. Plus your code looks quite elegant.